# Follow instructions to answer "what is me?"

Tags: word, wordplay

**Follow my instructions to find me out.**

> Choose from sea men—one stripped, then one elite,
> But they like to shift their places round.
> The rest can be the rapper star, Paul
> if only could his heart juggle.

**What is me, you ask?

Here's all you might need to know

(but probably already know):**

> You say me as a first man
> Fairly loved
> Used as object, yet not an object
> Men always have me,
> And I have me for company when alone.

**Mark my words — for all your actions,

ping if you see a pee, pee if you see a ping

Take the first and rejoice!

To understand, shift the focus from the start

that is, march right to left, left to right.

When exceptions you face, take the whole.**

> Setting the rule of
> answering doubts I
> the of
> riddling days on, I’m spend
> me as.

**"Umm...hard to understand." you say?

Huh! The answer's hidden in pure plain sight.

Here's another, mean old man.**

---

#### Say what do you think. What's the answer to this gibberish?

Answer (score 3):

To start off, the references in your narration seems to be related to:

> the bible (?)

Following your instructions:

**1st stanza analysis:**

> Jesus had 12 disciples chosen from sea men.  The elite: Simon Peter.  The stripped: Judas Iscariot.  The rest is Paul.

**2nd stanza analysis:**

> First man: Adam.  Men always have me : Adam's apple.  I have me for company: Maybe a reference to 'I'-phone product of apple company.

**Last two stanzas**

> *The last 2 stanzas should indicate I am in the right direction. Because, it is talking a lot about the letter 'P'. And  I have a lot of them : Peter Paul Apple*

Also:

> Going back to the first stanza, there are strong hints at anagrams- They like to shift their places, only if his heart could Juggle.

At last,

> 'Here is another mean old man ' indicates the answer is a name of an (enough-aged) person.

Am I in the right direction?

NB: I can't comment as  I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hey! Creative answer, but no---you're not in the right direction. I'm not even a Christian.

Answer (score 0):

A direction to the answer - deduced from the line
`Fly I’m not, the initialities might indicate but
Randoming the last of them is.`

> Solution might be from re-arranging the last alphabet of all the Capitalized (Initialized) words which comes to be `ETE(L)UYDNDIGIIYIGEGPTE`